# How is the new “DL” ranking in the Hackage package search calculated?

Tags: haskell, ranking, hackage

The [Hackage package search](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=base) as of now doesn't just give a list of all matches as it used to do, but allows sorting them in various ways. Notably, it is now possible to sort by *rating*, i.e. by how satisfied users were with the package (if people will actually start rating packages... this has been possible for a while but almost no votes are assigned yet), and by some “DL” criterium. I first assumed this somehow counted the reverse dependencies, i.e. described how many other packages depend on this one, but that can't seem to be the case since [`base` has only a value of 1692](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=base) whereas e.g. `base64-bytestring` has a whopping 7384.

So if that's not it, what does this number tell me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's downloads.

Clicking through to [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) for example shows:

> Downloads        21206 total (1692 in the last 30 days)

So it appears it's the last 30 days download count.

Comment: Makes sense. Interesting enough that `base` is ever downloaded from Hackage _at all_, seeing as it comes with the compiler...